# Why using __dict__ in __setattr__ causing infinite loop in __getattr__

Tags: python, getattr, setattr

I wrote a working program for this specified simplified Mesh class, but I can not make it work for real class with dozens of methods/properties.
I can not modify real Mesh class, and I can not make Object class extended Mesh.

This works fine:

```
    class Mesh:
        def __init__(self):
            self.hide_render = False


    class Object:
        def __init__(self, mesh_):
            self.mesh = mesh_

        def __getattr__(self, item):
            return self.mesh.__getattribute__(item) # infinite loop in this line

        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            if name == 'hide_render': # line to replace----------
                self.mesh.__setattr__(name, value)
            else:
                super().__setattr__(name, value)

    ob = Object(Mesh())

    print(ob.hide_render)
    print(ob.mesh.hide_render)
    ob.mesh.hide_render = True
    print(ob.hide_render)
    print(ob.mesh.hide_render)
    ob.hide_render = False
    print(ob.hide_render)
    print(ob.mesh.hide_render)
```

Output:

```
    False
    False
    True
    True
    False
    False
```

But when I want to do the same for real Mesh class with has much more than "hide _render" attribute by replacing the first line in **setattr** method with:
    `if name not in self.__dict__:`
or
    `if name in self.mesh.__dict__:`

I get an infinite loop in a **getattr** method.
Why? And how to solve this?

Comment: What do you think is involved in *setting* `self.mesh`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problems occur when `self.mesh` doesn't exist. If you're trying to defer all lookups for objects that don't yet exist in `self.__dict__` to `self.mesh`, you run into a problem when you can't lookup or assign to `self.mesh` itself.

There are a few ways you could fix that. You could use `self.__dict__['mesh']` or a `super().__setattr__` call from `__init__` rather than using a direct assignment. Or you could special case the name `mesh` in `__setattr__`:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, mesh):
        self.mesh = mesh

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.mesh, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__dict__ or name == 'mesh':   # special case for 'mesh' here!
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            setattr(self.mesh, name, value)
```

Comment: That is not what I was looking for after all.
Sens of using __dict__ was to make redundant corrections on every added property unnecessary. I mean when I will add self.something = something into init method, I will have to add something as another special case in setattr.
How to avoid this?

Comment: Using the `name in self.__dict__` test only works for attributes that are *already* in the instance dictionary. To get them into the dictionary in the first place, you need to do something else. Without more information, I can't really elaborate on my answer, but you could perhaps define a class level list or set of names that you'd check. Try something like `name in self.list_of_names` in place of `name == "mesh"`.